# Validar correos de un dominio especifico

Tags: php

Como podría validar que el correo que se registe tenga un dominio especifico, por ej.

```
juan@midominio.com         válido
maria@midominio.com        válido
pedro@otrodominio.com      no válido
```

lo que quiero es validar que todos los correos que se registren tenga obligatoriamente @midominio.com, lo intente con expresiones regulares pero el problema era que a permitía que las letras que usa @midominio se pudiera usar en cualquier orden por ej

```
juan@imdomioin.com  lo valida
```

es para usarlo, en que el usuario que se registre tenga el correo de la empresa.

Saludos.

---

Estoy trabajando con PHP, no estoy usando ningún framework, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL no me sirve en ese caso.

Otro detalle que se me paso el dominio es local juan@midominio.com.pa

Comment: Hola @edy-lasso ¿nos pones un ejemplo de código o nos comentas aunque sea en que lenguaje/plataforma/framework estás trabajando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = 'juan@midominio.com';
if( preg_match('/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@midominio\.com$/', $str) )
  echo 'Válido';
else
  echo 'Inválido';
```